# What's the term for 2 Dimensional tracks similar to the ones used on 3D printers?

Tags: automation, 3d-printing

I'm trying to do some research on a project that I'd like to work on.  My problem is that I am doing a terrible job googling, because I don't know what this technology is called.

[image]

Once I know what it's called, I feel like finding systems I can buy, or build, will be much more simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is called a gantry robot.

Answer (score 1):

By the word "tracks" I would assume you meant the guide rails on which
the 3D printers extruder is placed on.The rods which support the movement of the extruder are [smooth linear shafts](https://www.diy-india.com/shop/linear-shafts-and-slides/12mm-smooth-linear-shaft-125/).

They are connected to a servo motors.Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is of [linear bearings](https://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-linear-bearings/=1aje3ri) on what looks to me to be stainless steel shafting. You can also use [guide rails](https://www.mcmaster.com/#linear-bearings/=1aje489), which use a more specialized shaft than just a rod.